# See most visited sites on Google has disappeared?

Tags: google-account, statistics

I know for a fact a couple of years ago, I could go to `history.google.com` or `google.com/history` and it would greet me with statistics of my visited sites. It would show stuff like how many times I visited a website in a given time range (like last 365 days).

Anyone know why this has disappeared or where I can find it? I can't find it on the "new" `myactivity.google.com` site.

Comment: Works fine for me .... myactivity.google.com ...

Comment: @bummi Cool, which site is your most visited site? Eeeeeeeeexactly. That info isn't shown anymore.

Answer (score -1):

This can be nowadays found under **[myactivity.google.com/item?authuser=0](https://myactivity.google.com/item?authuser=0)** and the reason why you get nothing, could be that you have disabled individual modules at **[myaccount.google.com/activitycontrols](https://myaccount.google.com/activitycontrols?utm_source=my-activity&utm_medium=home&utm_campaign&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmyactivity.google.com%2Fmyactivity%3Futm_campaign%3Dcontinue)**

[image: 0]

Comment: Where do I see which site is my most visited? That information doesn't appear on `myactivity.google.com`. Don't get me wrong.. I have data. I just can't see which site I've visited most, which is what I used to be able to on `history.google.com`

Comment: @MortenMoulder that particular future got discontinued